# Spring-Data-Mongodb NoSuchMethodError when writing to db

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven, spring-data

I'm building a spring webapp using mongodb but recently I began having problems with writing to DB. The following stack trace is what I get.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [/afcrowther_blog]     threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoPersistentProperty.isWritable()Z] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoPersistentProperty.isWritable()Z
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:415)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:412)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:294)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:412)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:386)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:350)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:77)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.toDbObject(MongoTemplate.java:732)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:714)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:672)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:663)
```

After reading up the most common cause of this seems to be dependency mismatches, but I'm not sure which dependencies are actually compatible with one another in that case.

Pom.xml

```
    <spring.version>4.0.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.2</jackson.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>

    <finalName>afcrowther blog</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

These are mainly the latest release versions, although I changed spring framework to 4.0.7.Release to try and fix it, but I have also used 4.1.0.Release and the same exception occurs.

Thanks

EDIT: @Document Annotated class that throws the error, role set as a String until this problem is resolved

```
@Document(collection = "user")
public class UserModel{

@PersistenceConstructor
public UserModel(String id, String firstName, String surname, String email,
        String password, String role) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.role = role;
}

public UserModel(){

}

@Id
private String id;

@Field("firstName")
@Indexed
private String firstName;

@Field("surname")
private String surname;

@Field("email")
@Indexed(unique = true)
private String email;

@Field("password")
private String password;

@Field("role")
private String role;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getRole(){
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role){
    this.role = role;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're missing a setter in your `@Document` annotated class.

Comment: Pasted the class in, anything that jumps out as being inherently incorrect? Thanks

Comment: Can you run a `dependency:resolve`? The method in question was added in Commons 1.9.0, and it may be that some transitive dependency is making Maven pull an old version.

Comment: On a related note: Especially if this is a new project, use the Spring BOM for version management, and definitely consider Spring Boot to handle a lot of the dependency and config boilerplate.

Comment: Thanks, will try using spring BOM

Answer (score 0):

Update on the question, Upon changing to spring bom and spring data bom dependency management, the problem persisted.

However, removing the "@PersistenceConstructor" tag from the first constructor, and then switching around the order of the constructors fixed the issue. So the default constructor has to be first one in the file by the look of things. Not sure why, but there you go!